# Can Visual Studio warn of unsigned/signed type conversion?

Tags: c, visual-c++, type-conversion, compiler-warnings

gcc has `-Wsign-conversion` but I cannot find any equivalent in Visual Studio, even when its signed/unsigned warnings are explicitly enabled. For example, this 32-bit program that assigns a 32-bit unsigned type `size_t` to a 32-bit signed type `int` does not give a warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(3:4365)
#pragma warning(3:4388)
#pragma warning(3:4389)
#pragma warning(3:4287)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int x;
  x = strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(argv[2]);
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

`cl /W3 a.c` or /W4 or /Wall doesn't show a related warning.

gcc:

```
$ gcc -Wsign-conversion -o a a.c
a.c: In function 'main':
a.c:13:23: warning: conversion to 'int' from 'size_t' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
```

Comment: are you using an ancient version of MSVC? Because I got 3 warnings for your code https://godbolt.org/z/s4GvW4PYb

Comment: @phuclv This seems to have something to do with the source being compiled as c (.c) instead of c++ (.cpp). I will have to look into this more tomorrow.

Comment: I get the warning " warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data" on your code in Visual Studio ONLY when I enable "Detect 64-bit Portability Issues" = Yes (/Wp64)  (Under 'Configuration Properties'//  C/C++ // General )